User Model - roles and Relationships in ASP.NET Core Web API
I am working on a hobby project to develop my skills in asp.net core. I want user authentication in this project and for this purpose I am using microsoft identity. As a logged in user one should be able to create a food object and sell it. Similarly as a logged in user one should be able to buy this food. Initially the models I created are as follows;
   public class User : IdentityUser
   {
       public UserRole Role { get; set; }
       public Profile? Profile { get; set; }
   }

 public class Seller : User
 {
 public List<Food> Foods { get; set; } = new List<Food>();
 }

public class Buyer : User
{
    public List<Food> Foods { get; set; } = new List<Food>();

}

  public class Category
  {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public required string Name { get; set; }
  }

 public class Food
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }
     public required string Name { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
     public required string Description { get; set; }
     public required string Ingredients { get; set; }
     public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
     public required string SellerId { get; set; } 
     public required Seller Seller { get; set; }
     public Guid FoodImageId { get; set; }
     public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
     public List<FoodImage>? FoodImage { get; set; }
     public required Category Category { get; set; }
 }

 public class FoodImage
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public Guid FoodId { get; set; }  
     public required Food Food { get; set; }
     public required string Image { get; set; }
 }

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public required string BuyerId { get; set; }
    public required string SellerId { get; set; }
    public Guid FoodId { get; set; }
    public required Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
    public required Seller Seller { get; set; }
    public required Food Food { get; set; }
}

 public class OrderItem
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
     public required Order Order { get; set; }
     public Guid FoodId { get; set; }
     public required Food Food { get; set; }
     public int Quantity { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
 }

 public class Profile
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public required string Address { get; set; }
     public required string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public required string City { get; set; }
     public required string Country { get; set; }
     public required string PostCode { get; set; }
     public string? Bio { get; set; }
     public string? ProfileImage { get; set; }
     public required string UserId { get; set; }
     public required User User { get; set; }
 }

My initial thought was to have a role for buyer and seller while registration. When I implemented microsoft identity, while registraion process it only ask for an email and password - now one solution could be to do some customization and add an other input to ask user if user is buyer or seller. But now I start thinking do I really need roles like buyer and seller in my project? Since I am new to asp.net core and have limited knowledge I need someone who can help to make this decision. The idea behind this project is, as an logged in user I should be able to post a food and other user can buy it. But only the owner user is able to update the food.
You are welcome to suggest anyother changes in the other models as well. Thank you for the help in advance.

Your project concept is solid, but your current model structure could use some refinement to better align with your requirements. Specifically:
Do You Need Separate Buyer and Seller Roles?
No, you likely don't need separate Buyer and Seller roles. Any logged-in user should be able to act as both a buyer and a seller depending on the context. This simplifies your model by eliminating the Seller and Buyer classes and using a single User class for all users.
Revised Models and Suggestions
Here’s a revised approach:
User Class
Keep User as a single class inheriting from IdentityUser. Add a collection for foods they sell and orders they make:
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public Profile? Profile { get; set; }
    public List<Food> FoodsForSale { get; set; } = new List<Food>();
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
}

Food Class
Make SellerId a UserId reference and ensure User navigational property works bidirectionally:
public class Food
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public required string Description { get; set; }
    public required string Ingredients { get; set; }
    public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
    public required string SellerId { get; set; } 
    public required User Seller { get; set; }
    public Guid FoodImageId { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<FoodImage>? FoodImages { get; set; }
    public required Category Category { get; set; }
}

Order and OrderItem Classes
Ensure orders link to buyers and sellers through their user accounts, and include navigational properties for clarity:
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public required string BuyerId { get; set; }
    public required User Buyer { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<OrderItem>();
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public required Order Order { get; set; }
    public Guid FoodId { get; set; }
    public required Food Food { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

Profile Class
No major changes are needed here, but ensure it’s optional for users to have a profile.
Customizing Microsoft Identity
If you want to allow users to specify additional details during registration (e.g., their initial intent to sell or buy), you can extend the registration process. However, you don't need separate roles because every user can be both a buyer and seller.

Extend the registration form to include optional fields like Profile.Address or a "Wants to Sell" checkbox.
After user creation, initialize additional properties based on these inputs.
Authorization
To ensure only the seller can update their own food:

Use User.IsInRole("Seller") only if you define a seller role (not recommended).
Alternatively, enforce ownership checks directly in the service or controller:
if (food.SellerId != User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
{
    return Unauthorized();
}

